# in php this error show when i am inserting the data by form

Tags: php

Error: insert into products (product_cat, product_name, product_pric, product_desc, product_image, product_keyword, product_ingrid) values ('5','','', '','','','')
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'product_pric' at row 1 
what is this error and how to resolve

Comment: You're trying to insert an empty string into an integer column - which part of the error message doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies - you are trying to insert an empty string (the "") into a column which defined as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty string to a integer field. It must be null (if column is nullable) or an integer.